# Temurin OpenJDK 11 installer hanged on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: scala, macos-monterey, adoptopenjdk

I am trying to install AdoptOpenJDK 11 from https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot for using Scala . But it's installer is stuck . It's been 15 minutes its still trying to install . It is not letting me close the installer also .

Please help .

Mac os details :

```
  System Version:   macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 21.1.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    Prashant’s MacBook Air
  Username: Prashant Singh (prashantsingh)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  System Integrity Protection:  Enabled
  Time since boot:  2 days 18:43
```

[image]

[image]

---

Update :

I forced quit the installer .
Restarted the Mac .
Now it is installed

```
prashantsingh@Prashants-MacBook-Air: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
$ source ~/.zshrc                                                                                                    [6:32:26]
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'zsh-syntax-highlighting' not found
current java version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
```

Looks like a bug to me . Is it safe to use above Java version for learning Scala ?

Comment: Yes, Temurin 11 is a good, safe choice for learning Scala.